# Strange Cron alerts

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, ce-1.9.2.4

A few days ago a started receiving some alerts from Magento cron set up in cPanel. This happened since about 7.15 am to 9.15 am. Now I'm no longer receiving these alerts, but I would really like to understand what caused this.

The cron setup in cPanel is: `php -q /path-to/public_html/cron.php`

And these are alerts/errors I received:

> /path-to/public_html/cron.sh: line 46: /dev/null: Permission denied
>       Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc
>   /path-to/public_html/cron.sh: line 47: cannot redirect standard input from /dev/null: No such file or directory
>
> /path-to/public_html/cron.sh: line 46: /dev/null: Permission denied
>   grep: write error: Broken pipe
>   /path-to/public_html/cron.sh: line 47: cannot redirect standard input from /dev/null: No such file or directory
>
> php: error while loading shared libraries: libmcrypt.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is a Magento 1.9.2.4 install on shared hosting. I have got "AOE Scheduler" extension installed with just basic setup..nothing fancy.

So I am wondering what may have caused these cron alerts? How can I investigate further?

Cron `php -q /path-to/public_html/cron.php` was not modified before or after these errors..and what's even more strange is that the alerts stopped by themselves.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a problem with shared hosting. Do you have SSH access to debug the commands manually?

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for your input. I have SSH enabled but not much debugging experience about this. Have you got any advice?